# Datetime in Dwoo - problems getting time to display as "2pm - 3pm"

Tags: php, datetime, time, dwoo

I've created my Dwoo site, and it works well.

However, the time displays as the following:

```
14:00-15:00 Your Event
```

This is the section of the tpl:

```
            {loop $records}<li >
            <div class="list-inner">
                        <h1 class="schedule-title">
                <span><a href="{$link1}">{$eventtime date_format %L %P} - {$showtime1 date_format %l %p} {$wcwnr}</a></span>
            </h2>
            <a href="{$link1}"><img src="{$image}" width="115" height="60"/></a>
            <p class="listpara">{$eventinfo}
 <a class="read-more" href="{$link1}">Click here for info</a></p>
            </div>
        </li>{/loop}
```

It **should** display the event as this:

```
2pm-3pm Your Event
Description
```

but it doesn't.

What have I done wrong here?

I've tried to fix this but just can't work out what's gone wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding quotes...

```
{$eventtime date_format "%L %P"}
```